# Angular Material Autocomplete control once Opened is not getting closed for external actions like Page level scroll

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-7

As shown in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmarv-pzt16h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html), I'm facing an issue with Angular Material Autocomplete control in which the control stays opened on external events like Page Scroll as shown in the attached sample and the issues even occurs in the Angular Material demo [site](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples). [image: Issue Screenshot]

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Click on Autocomplete control and let it stay expanded.
2. Try to do page level scroll to the bottom
   (https://v7.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples),
   the Autocomplete control doesn't collapse/close.
3. I've tried to place focusout event as in the example
   (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfuvpb?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html),
   even though the Autocomplete control collapses on Page level scroll
   click
   (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfuvpb?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts)
   but on more issue came up like the selected option doesn't apply to
   Autocomplete control.

**Expected Behavior**:
On any action outside of the Autocomplete control e.g., Page level scroll should close the Autocomplete control

**Actual Behavior**:
The Autocomplete control stays expanded and is not user friendly behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well-know [issue in github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10079)

The workaround for that is to put `cdkScrollable` on your wrapper that has scroll and override `MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_SCROLL_STRATEGY` provider.

**html**

```
<div class="content-container" cdkScrollable>
```

Make sure you imported `import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';`

> **Note:** you don't need to put cdkScrollable if it is a body scroll

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Overlay, CloseScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

export function scrollFactory(overlay: Overlay): () => CloseScrollStrategy {
    return () => overlay.scrollStrategies.close();
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_SCROLL_STRATEGY, useFactory: scrollFactory, deps: [Overlay] }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmarv-pey3s3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts)**

Comment: Looks like the fix doesn't work in IE11. I think CdkScrolling is not supported in IE11, any other way to fix this for IE11?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with Angular Material version?

Comment: not really sure as i don't see any precautionary measure on using CDK Scrolling in https://v7.material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview for IE11

Comment: Another way is to subscribe to scroll event and call `autoCompleteTrigger.closePanel()` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmarv-qljufs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html Also, I'd suggest you to subscribe to scroll event outside of Angular zone for better performance

Comment: Apologies missed the above comments, will try it now and get back to you soon.

Comment: It worked but I've encountered a different issue when multiple Autocomplete controls are present in which only the first Autocomplete closes on Scroll even if the Autocomplete #id is different for the rest of the Auto complete controls. The issue is reproducible in stackblitz sample. Could you please check?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmarv-xfnjrd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html

Comment: I added answer to your addition question